# Regex matching a dll but not the directory

Tags: regex

I have a conf file that is loading plugins. I need to parse and match a certain plugin in a directory but not others in the same directory:

```
plugin: c:\program files\application\abc\abc.dll
plugin: c:\program files\application\abc\xyz.dll
```

I need to match the abc.dll only but due to the fact that the abc is also in the dir name, it matches both lines but I dont want xyz.dll

So I tried:
^plugin:(.*)(abc.dll)

So ^ = start of line, then plugin, then .* anything, then abc escape dot dll.

But it doesnt seem to work. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What are you using?  Shell script, java, etc...

Comment: will be using boost::regex but I need to learn more I think :)

Comment: Why do you say `^plugin:(.*)(abc.dll)` doesn't work? It matches only `plugin: c:\program files\application\abc\abc.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the dot in abc.dll. Try escaping it so it's not a wild card.

```
^plugin:(.*)(abc\.dll)
```

Comment: His regex `^plugin:(.*)(abc.dll)` and yours match the line with abc.dll

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use this regexp:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.dll)
```

Here is [example](http://regexr.com?30vcn)

Comment: or `^plugin:(.*)([^\.]+\.dll)`

Comment: This matches **abc.dll** and **xyz.dll** in the 2nd parenthesized group.